# Dynamic calculation using Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, dynamic-forms

I'm trying to create dynamic calculator using Vuetify. Here's my code

```
<v-row class="mt-8 align-self-center">
    <v-col cols="2">
         <v-text-field :value="weight" label="Weight (kg)" placeholder="Type here" filled rounded></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="2">
         <v-text-field :value="distance"  label="Distance (km)" placeholder="Type here" filled rounded></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
<v-card v-model="result" height="100" width="500">
                Estimated shipping cost is: {{result}}
</v-card>
```

and here's my script

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            inputDistance: '',
            inputWeight: '',
            result: ''
        }
    },
    computed: {
        result: function(){
            var totalCost = this.inputDistance * this.inputWeight *2000;
            return totalCost;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried using v-model too but it still doesn't work. Any idea on what I suppose to write?
Thanks!

Comment: Did my solution work?

Comment: If your issue is resolved..pls consider accepting my answer..thankyou :)

Comment: @Amaarrockz yes it works, thank you so much! sorry i just checked this :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `:value` with `v-model` in your `v-text-field`, use the variable names and then remove `v-model` from `v-card`.

```
<v-row class="mt-8 align-self-center">
    <v-col cols="2">
         <v-text-field v-model="inputWeight" label="Weight (kg)" placeholder="Type here" filled rounded></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
    <v-col cols="2">
         <v-text-field v-model="inputDistance"  label="Distance (km)" placeholder="Type here" filled rounded></v-text-field>
    </v-col>
</v-row>
<v-card height="100" width="500">
                Estimated shipping cost is: {{result}}
</v-card>
```

and then use parseFloat in computed

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            inputDistance: '',
            inputWeight: '',
            /** removed result variable **/
        }
    },
computed: {
        result: function(){
            var totalCost = parseFloat(this.inputDistance, 10) * parseFloat(this.inputWeight,10) *2000;
            return totalCost;
        }
    }
}
```